# How to get thease object array to single array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, stdclass

Please help to sort out below...

I need to get following kind of a array in to a single array in PHP

Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [title]=>name1 
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
           [title]=>name2  
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title]=>name3 
        )

)
```

this array in to

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [title]=>name1 
        )


    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
           [title]=>name2  
        )


    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title]=>name3 
        )

)
```

Comment: What did you try? Any single of the array_ functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `array_merge()` with all the arrays as parameters will return the joined array. Keep in mind, however, that same-valued keys will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()` is Merge arrays into one array:

for eg:-

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
$a2=array("c"=>"blue","b"=>"yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_merge` like

```
$new_arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
```

Or like

```
$arr4 = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
$new_arr = array_merge($arr4,$arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, may be it will help you.

```
$x = (object) array(array('title'=>'name1'));
$y = (object) array(array('title'=>'name2'));
//both arrays will be merged including duplicates
$arry1 = (array)$x;
$arry2 = (array)$y;
$result = array_merge($arry1, $arry2 );
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $result)));
$result = (object)$result;
```